# From pop window active the parent window

Tags: javascript, popup

Using JavaScript I open the pop window and parent window is inactive at this time,
I wanted to active parentwindow through popwindow. (this is a web project on Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually window.opener in JavaScript to get at the window that opened at popup.